# Can VBA code assign the line row in IDE it is currently executing to a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Im fairly new to programming and I stumbled an idea, to make a progressbar through UserForm, that will display % of completion depending on this formula (Current line of code/Last line of code)*100 Is it even possible? I found no answers anywhere on that would cover this topic.

Comment: What if the code contains a loop or a call to another method?

Comment: @KostasK.I have two progress bar, one that shows overall percentage of completion and then a "subprogressbar" that calculates percentage of completion of individual loops

Comment: If you want a discrete progress bar in some loop-less top-level sub. Perhaps you can write a sub which increments the progress bar by a discrete amount and put e.g. 10 invocations of it in strategic places in the code. I don't think that VBA provides programmatic access to which line of code that the interpreter is currently executing.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for your comment and shedding a light on my problem!

Comment: To add to my previous comment. If you manually update an overall progress bar, your progress increments can reflect actual timing information that you obtain from profiling your code, something which would be more meaningful than simply percentage of lines of code executed. You could also have a label control in the progress bar that can display a message such as "extracting data ... " which you change when you update the bar. The update sub could have e.g. an optional string parameter.